# Generator usage for log analysing

Tags: generator

I have a working python code to analyze logs. Logs are at least 10 MBytes of size and they can sometimes reach 250-300 Mbytes depending on failures, retries.

I used generator which could yield the big file as chunks and it can be configurable and I normally use 1 or 2 Mbytes of log to yield. So I analyze logs as 1Mb chunks for verification of some tests.

My problem is when I use generator it could bring up some edge cases. In log analyzing I check for subsequent appearance of some patterns as the following, so if only those 4 list seen then I keep them for next verification part of the code. The following 4 pattern can be seen in the logs once or twice, not more.

```
listA
listB
listC
listD
```

if these all occurs subsequently then I keep them all to evaluate in next step, otherwise ignore..

However now there is a small change the following could happen, some patterns (lists as I use regex findall method to find patterns) can be in next chunk to complete the check. So in the following I have 3 matching case chunk 3-4 and 5-6 and 7-8  creates the condition to take into account.

```
---- chunk 1 -----

listA

listB

----- chunk 2 -----


nothing

----- chunk 3 -----
listA
 
listB

----- chunk 4 -----

listC
listD

----- chunk 5 -----

listA


----- chunk 6 -----

listB

listC
listD

---- chunk 7 ------
listA
listB
listC
----- chunk 8 ------

listD
---------------------
```

Usually it does not happen like this, some patterns (B,C,D) is mostly seen subsequently in logs but listA can be seen 20 maybe the most 30 rows earlier than the rest. But any scenario like above can happen.

Please advise a good approach, I'm not sure what to use, I know there is next() function can be used to check next chunk, in such case

should I use any([listA, listB, listC, listD]) method and if any of the patterns occurs then do I need to check one by one the rest in next chunk like the following?:

```
if any([listA, listB, listC, listD]):

Then here check which of the patterns not seen and keep them in a notSeen list then check them one by one in next chunk?
next_chunk = next(gen_func(chunksize))
isListA = re.findall(pattern, next_chunk)
```

Or maybe I completely miss an easier approach for this little project. please let me know your thoughts as you might experience such situation before.

Answer (score 0):

I have used next_chunk = next(gen_func(chunksize))
and added necessary if statements underneath to check only 1 next log piece becase I would arrange log chunks with a generator suitably:

I shared only a part of the code as the rest confidential

```
import re, os
def __init__(self, logfile):
    self.read = self.ReadLog(logfile)
    self.search = self.SearchData(logfile)
    self.file = os.path.abspath(logfile)
    self.data = self.read.read_in_chunks
    
r_search_combined, scan_result, r_complete, r_failed = [], [], [], []

def test123(self, r_reason: str, cyc: int, b_r):
    ''' Usage : verify_log.py
            --log ${LOGS_FOLDER}/log --reason r_low 1 <True | False>'''
    ret = False
    r_count = 2*int(cyc) if b_r.lower() == "true" else int(cyc)
    r_search_combined, scan_result, r_complete, r_failed = [], [], [], []
    result_pattern = self.search.r_scan_pattern()
    def check_patterns(chunk):
        search_cached = re.findall(self.search.r_search_cached, chunk)
        search_full = re.findall(self.search.r_search_full, chunk)
        scan_complete = re.findall(self.search.r_scan_complete, chunk)
        scan_result = re.findall(result_pattern, chunk)
        r_complete = re.findall(self.search.r_auth_complete, chunk)
        return search_cached, search_full, scan_complete, scan_result, r_complete 

    with open(self.file) as rf:
        for idx, piece in enumerate(self.data(rf), start=1):
            is_failed = re.findall(self.search.r_failure, piece)
            if is_failed:
                print(f'general failure received : {is_failed}')
                r_failed.extend(is_failed)

            is_r_search_cached, is_r_search_full, is_scan_complete, is_scan, is_r_complete = check_patterns(piece)

            if (is_r_search_cached or is_r_search_full) and all([is_scan_complete, is_scan, is_r_complete]):
                if is_r_search_cached:
                    r_search_combined.extend(is_r_search_cached)
                if is_r_search_full:
                    r_search_combined.extend(is_r_search_full)
                scan_result.extend(is_scan)
                r_complete.extend(is_r_complete)

            elif (is_r_search_cached or is_r_search_full) and not any([is_scan, is_r_complete]): 
                next_piece = next(self.data(rf))
                _, _, _, is_scan_next, is_r_complete_next = check_patterns(next_piece) 
                if (is_r_search_cached or is_r_search_full) and all([is_scan_next, is_r_complete_next]):
                    r_search_combined.extend(is_r_search_cached)
                    r_search_combined.extend(is_r_search_full)
                    scan_result.extend(is_scan_next)
                    r_complete.extend(is_r_complete_next)

            elif (is_r_search_cached or is_r_search_full) and is_scan and not is_r_complete:
                next_piece = next(self.data(rf))
                _, _, _, _, is_r_complete_next = check_patterns(next_piece)
                if (is_r_search_cached or is_r_search_full) and all([is_scan, is_r_complete_next]):
                    r_search_combined.extend(is_r_search_cached)
                    r_search_combined.extend(is_r_search_full)
                    scan_result.extend(is_scan)
                    r_complete.extend(is_r_complete_next)
```